# I would like to eliminate the white space in between each of the colors for each column for my ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to eliminate the white space in between each of the colors for each column

[image]

I have used the below code

```
ggplot(data=TranscriptionTargetsClassTable, aes(x=Target, y = Class)) +
 geom_tile(aes(fill = Class), color = "black", size = 0.1) + 
 coord_flip() + 
 theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

Comment: `ggplot(data=TranscriptionTargetsClassTable, aes(x=Target, y = 1,fill = Class)) + 
      geom_tile()+ coord_flip() + theme_classic(base_size = 16)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing two ways to interpret your Q - First, remove the white space by aligning the plot into a single column.

```
TranscriptionTargetsClassTable <- data.frame(Target=sample(LETTERS,10,replace=FALSE),
                                             Class=sample(c('A','B','C'),10,replace=TRUE))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=TranscriptionTargetsClassTable, aes(x=Target, y = 1,fill = Class)) + 
  geom_tile()+ coord_flip() + theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Or, reorder the plot, such that there is no white space between rows with the same color.

```
TranscriptionTargetsClassTable$Target2 <- factor(TranscriptionTargetsClassTable$Target, 
                                                 levels=unique(TranscriptionTargetsClassTable$Target[order(TranscriptionTargetsClassTable$Class)]), ordered=TRUE)
ggplot(data=TranscriptionTargetsClassTable, aes(x=Target2, y = Class,fill = Class)) + 
  geom_tile()+ coord_flip() + theme_classic(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Let me know if you had a different intent.

Comment: I had the some intent what you have shown here. I am going to try this ands let you know about it.

Comment: It worked exactly the way you presented it. Thanks a lot for looking into it. :)

Comment: @Abhimanyu - Glad I could help. If the answer isn't complete, let me know. Otherwise, if this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks